# How to get SQLite database file from firebase storage to my android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to download my database or any file from Firebase Storage and store it to internal storage.

I use this method to download an image, but not working. can you tell me How do I do this? (this method is for a test, I wanna download database.)

```
private void downloadFile() {
    storageReference = firebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    ref = storageReference.child("im.png");
    File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "im.png");
    if (!rootPath.exists())
        rootPath.mkdirs();
    final File localFile = new File(rootPath, "imagename.txt");
    ref.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Don", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're referring to both a database, and storage. Within the context of Firebase, those are separate products each with their own APIs. What specifically are you trying to download into your Android app? Can you show a screenshot of it?

Comment: I write a dictionary app. my words, synonym and ... has into SQLite database. I upload this database to Storage firebase. now, I want to download this database to the app and use it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I updated your question to reflect that information. If you change the `im.png` to point to a SQLite file that you uploaded to Firebase Storage., what isn't working about the code at the moment?

Comment: this code is correct? it's finished with many errors. can you tell me how to download a file from firebase?

Comment: Your code looks similar to what's in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_to_a_local_file. If it gives errors, update your question to show the exact error message.